# Clang --coverage and -fprofile options

Tags: c++, clang

Clang has a few options related to coverage-style profiling. The [command line reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) doesn't really say what any of them do:

```
--coverage
-fprofile-arcs
-fprofile-instr-generate
-ftest-coverage
-fcoverage-mapping
```

According to the [llvm-cov docs](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html) `--coverage` enables `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage` and maybe more.

Both `-fprofile-..` flags add instrumentation in some way to record execution counts, but do they do exactly the same thing? If so why have both?

The llvm-cov docs say to use `-fprofile-arcs` with `llvm-cov gcov` but `-fprofile-instr-generate` with `llvm-cov show`. Why? What is going on here?

And what do `-fcoverage-mapping` and `-ftest-coverage` do exactly?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html has some information on the source coverage side of things.  The GCC side I expect has info from GCC docs :)

Answer (score 11):

I started reading [the code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a58d0437d1e17d53d7bffea598d77789dd6d28b6/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Clang.cpp), and as far as I can tell:

`--coverage` enables `-ftest-coverage`, `-fprofile-arcs`, and also adds `-u__llvm_runtime_variable` on Linux, or something like that.

`-fprofile-arcs` and `-fprofile-instr-generate` *are* different. The former adds `-femit-coverage-data` and the latter adds `-fprofile-instrument=clang` (other options are "none" or "llvm").

`-ftest-coverage` adds `-femit-coverage-notes`

`-fcoverage-mapping` adds `-fcoverage-mapping`

Then the options have the following effect:

- `-ftest-coverage`: ["Don't run the GCov pass, for testing."](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/5855293e6fbb63b4f7a0fb800e8ab69696b9882f/include/clang/Frontend/CodeGenOptions.def#L53) (that is... confusing)
- `-femit-coverage-data`: Create a GCDA file.
- `-femit-coverage-notes`: Create a GCNO file.
- `-fprofile-instrument=clang`: One of [the following options](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a452f439ff2c78f40fe995964ce63a77c5c1b2d7/include/clang/Frontend/CodeGenOptions.h#L96):

```
ProfileNone,       // Profile instrumentation is turned off.
ProfileClangInstr, // Clang instrumentation to generate execution counts
                   // to use with PGO.
ProfileIRInstr,    // IR level PGO instrumentation in LLVM.
```

So that answers some questions, but there does indeed seem to be two totally different profiling systems and I'm not sure of the difference.